# Book Identification: Children's book involving a scary amusement park

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to identify a children's (YA) book I read as a child around the late 80s or early 90s, although I'm not sure when it would have actually been published.  The main points I remember are that it was involving children going on a school trip to an amusement/theme park.  I can't remember what the scary element was but it could have been monsters/werewolves/vampires, that sort of thing. One part I do remember is two of the children seeing their teacher go overhead in a cable car and calling her the flying nun, so maybe it was a Catholic school with nuns as teachers?

Comment: [*The Belch Park Field Trip*](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/38887572-the-belch-park-field-trip) might match, except for timing.